# How to resolve using parent hierarchy interfaces using DryIOC

Tags: c#, dryioc

I have the following objects structure

```
public interface IParser {}
public interface IAction : IParser {}
public interface ICommand : IParser {}

//impl
public class Action1 : IAction {}
public class Command1 : ICommand {}

//registration
container.Register<IAction, Action1>();
container.Register<ICommand, Command1>();

//resolve
var parsersList = container.Resolve<IList<IParser>>() //expected: parsersList.Count=2 actual count=0
```

Is there any way to make some kind of binding between these parent and child interfaces in DryIOC?

EDIT:

I did some research and found that RegisterMany did the trick but I am a bit confused because

```
//registration
//container.Register<IAction, Action1>(); //if I drop these two lines \_____
//container.Register<ICommand, Command1>();                           /     |
container.RegisterMany<Action1>(); // and use these lines                   |
container.RegisterMany<Command1>();                                         |
//resolve                                                                   |
var parsersList = container.Resolve<IList<IParser>>() //WORKS Count = 2     |
container.Resolve<IAction>() //not working Unable to resolve IAction    <---|
container.Resolve<ICommand>() //Same here for ICommand                  <---|
container.Resolve<IParser>() //not working either
```

If I uncomment back individual registrations lines above, Resolve works for IAction and ICommand but not for IParser.

It seems that `RegisterMany` is not registering parent types properly...

Edit2:

I changed my registration to following, using `RegisterMapping`

```
container.Register<IAction, Action1>();
container.Register<ICommand, Command1>();
container.RegisterMapping<IParsable, ICommand>(); //1st registered mapping
container.RegisterMapping<IParsable, IAction>();
container.Resolve<IList<IParser>>().Count = 1 //instead of 2.
```

The item in the IParsers list is of type of the first registered mapping, in this case `ICommand`

I am using DryIOC v2.6.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is working and explaining [sample on .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/VUpc3L).

The code:

```
    var container = new Container();

    container.RegisterMany<Action1>();                 
    container.RegisterMany<Command1>();

    var parsersList = container.Resolve<IList<IParser>>();

    // works fine
    container.Resolve<IAction>();

    // works fine
    container.Resolve<ICommand>();

    // Throws because IParser is registered multiple times (as Action and as Command),
    // and container is unable to select one. This is precisely what exception is saying.
    //container.Resolve<IParser>();
```

The exception in DryIoc supposed to be guiding you in this case.

#### Update:

In case you want to include non-public service types for `RegisterMany` use:

```
container.RegisterMany<Action1>(nonPublicServiceTypes: true);                 
container.RegisterMany<Command1>(nonPublicServiceTypes: true);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately I did as as you instructed but it didn't work, I don't know for what reason but I think something is wrong with my code. I will isolate these components in a clean project and check if it works or not. btw I am using the SRC version not DLL version from NuGet. Thanks again!

Comment: What exceptions did it raise? Src should not be different from dll package functionality-wise.

Comment: Unable to resolve `App.Interfaces.IAction.`

Where no service registrations found

  and number of Rules.FallbackContainers: 0

  and number of Rules.UnknownServiceResolvers: 0

Comment: Strange, what ais visiblity of IAction interface? Is it public?

Comment: Also you may enable non public service types in RegisterMany via optional parameter nonPublicServiceTypes: true

Comment: Yes, that was it, the interfaces were not public, setting `nonPublicServiceTypes: true` fixed the issue. Thank you very much, and sorry for causing any trouble. can you please add this solution to your answer above, I will mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: Updated the answer.